# Ruby HTTP post with session cookie

Tags: ruby, http, post, cookies

I'm trying to write a Ruby script to use the API on the image gallery site Piwigo, this requires you to login first with one HTTP post and upload an image with another post.

This is what I've got so far but it doesn't work, just returns a 401 error, can anyone see where I am going wrong?

```
require 'net/http'
require 'pp'

http = Net::HTTP.new('mydomain.com',80)
path = '/piwigo/ws.php'
data = 'method=pwg.session.login&username=admin&password=password'
resp, data = http.post(path, data, {})
if (resp.code == '200')
    cookie = resp.response['set-cookie']
    data = 'method=pwg.images.addSimple&image=image.jpg&category=7'
    headers = { "Cookie" => cookie }
    resp, data = http.post(path, data, headers)
    puts resp.code
    puts resp.message
end
```

Which gives this response when run;

```
$ ruby piwigo.rb
401
Unauthorized
```

There is a Perl example on their API page which I was trying to convert to Ruby http://piwigo.org/doc/doku.php?id=dev:webapi:pwg.images.addsimple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the nice_http gem: https://github.com/MarioRuiz/nice_http
NiceHttp will take care of your cookies so you don't have to do anything

```
require 'nice_http'
path = '/piwigo/ws.php'
data = '?method=pwg.session.login&username=admin&password=password'

http = NiceHttp.new('http://example.com')
resp = http.get(path+data)

if resp.code == 200
    resp = http.post(path)
    puts resp.code
    puts resp.message
end
```

Also if you want you can add your own cookies by using http.cookies

Answer (score 0):

You can use a gem called `mechanize`. It handles cookies transparently.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look, I thought that more for driving a webpage than accessing a web API though?